# How to show android installation pop up before app downloading?

Tags: android

Is it possible to show android installation pop up before app downloading as in android market?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. How will you get control,even before your app is in the device?

Comment: When we download an app from market, they show installation screen before the app download. So I guess all we need may be packagename, permissions etc to show the dialog. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Even if you know all that, how will you still run it, as your app hasnt been downloaded yet?

Comment: I just need to show that window with permissions and all that kind of things and once user click on the some button on the window the actual download will start

Comment: Like @althaf_tvm says, your application is not installed how then can it show a notification? It is not possible. If you are offering installations from outside of the market you can put permission information on your download website.

Comment: If I have got the list of permissions, packagename etc of an app, can I show the permission window like the one which is shown during apk installation?

Comment: @althaf_tvm please come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6784/android-talk to chat